# Simplest method for enabling the pipeline operator in Vue single file components

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, babeljs

What's the simplest method for enabling the pipeline operator in Vue single file components, both in the `<template>` and in the `<script>`?

Example:

```html
<template>
  <span>
    <!-- should display as −15,395.94 -->
    {{ amount |> currency }}
  </span>
</template>

<script>
  const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  });

  // though they look like the same symbol, they are not
  const HYPHEN_MINUS = "-";
  const MINUS_SIGN = "−";

  function hyphenToMinus(value) {
    return String(value).replace(HYPHEN_MINUS, MINUS_SIGN);
  }
  
  export default {
    data: _ => ({
      amount: -15395.94,
    }),
    methods: {
      currency: value => value
        |> currencyFormatter.format
        |> hyphenToMinus
      ,
    },
  };
</script>
```

Note: I want to use the Vue CLI's [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/) instead of working directly with webpack config.

Note: I don't want to use [Vue filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html). There's [talk of removing filters](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/6#issuecomment-456121927) in a future version of Vue, and I'm hoping to try out "standard" JS syntax for this functionality.

About the pipeline operator in Babel: [@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator.html).

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline operators are called filters in Vue.js.

Here is the documentation for this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

In your case you could have this code:

```
<template>
  <span>
    {{ 15 | double }}
  </span>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      double: value => value * 2,
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: My fault for not being more clear. Updated the question to say that I don't want to use Vue filters because (1) there's talk of removing filters in a future version of Vue, and (2) I'd like to also use the pipeline operator in the <script> block, too.

Answer (score 1):

After two days of research finally found the answer for Vue 3. Don't know if it works for Vue 2 though.

For enable [babel plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-parser#plugins) in templates of single file components you need to specify them in the parameter `compilerOptions.expressionPlugins` of `vue-loader` loader.

If you use Vue CLI:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.compilerOptions = {
          expressionPlugins: [['pipelineOperator', { proposal: 'fsharp' }]],
        }
        return options
      })
  },
}
```

If you use Webpack:

```
// webpack.config.json
module.exports = {
  // other options
  module: {
    rules: [
      // other rules
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'vue-loader',
          options: {
            compilerOptions: {
              expressionPlugins: [['pipelineOperator', { proposal: 'fsharp' }]],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]
  }
}
```